# Mysql long execution query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, laravel-5

I have table with 38k rows and I use this query to compare item id from items table with item id from posted_domains table.

```
select * from `items` 
where `items`.`source_id` = 2 and `items`.`source_id` is not null 
    and not exists (select * 
                    from `posted_domains` 
                    where `posted_domains`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` and `domain_id` = 1)
order by `item_created_at` asc limit 1
```

This query took **8s**. I don't know if is a problem with my query or my mysql is bad configured. This query is generated by Laravel relations like

```
$items->doesntHave('posted', 'and', function ($q) use ($domain) {
    $q->where('domain_id', $domain->id);
});
```

Comment: which columns have indexes in your table?

Comment: just id column on each tables

Comment: I added indexes on posted table and now is much faster 156ms. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORRELATED subqueries can be rather slow (as they are often executed repeatedly, once for each row in the outer query), this *might* be faster.

```
select * 
from `items` 
where `items`.`source_id` = 2 
   and `items`.`source_id` is not null 
   and item_id not in (
      select DISTINCT item_id 
      from `posted_domains` 
      where `domain_id` = 1) 
order by `item_created_at` asc 
limit 1
```

I say *might* because subqueries in where are also rather slow in MySQL.

This LEFT JOIN will probably be the fastest.

```
select * 
from `items` 
LEFT JOIN (
      select DISTINCT item_id 
      from `posted_domains` 
      where `domain_id` = 1) AS subQ
ON items.item_id = subQ.item_id
where `items`.`source_id` = 2 
   and `items`.`source_id` is not null 
   and subQ.item_id is null
order by `item_created_at` asc 
limit 1;
```

Since it is a *no matches* scenario, it technically doesn't even need to be a subquery; and might be faster as a direct left join, but that will depend on indexes, and possibly actual data values.

Comment: I think **and item_id not in** it was a wrong typo in the first query right? The query is very fast.

Comment: @user3233336 not a typo unless `NOT EXISTS` was a typo in the query in your question. _You can think of the subquery in my first suggestion as a list of all the item_id values in the "exists" set._